# Local Notification timer reset

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

I have problem with timer reset. How to rest the timer to start counting for notification, which means 200 second delay before the last button pressed?

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:200];
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.alertBody = @" More Quiz ";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Just call `cancelLocalNotification:` and schedule a new one.